# runnable jar - org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I've a JPA project that correctly runs in Eclipse, but when I try to export a runnable jar and run it from cmd it throws this exception.

I have 2 persistence units in the project, it seems the second one is not recognized.

The first exeception seems to be thrown by below error

> "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Mongo_PU"

**Note**: "Mongo_PU" is present in persistence.xml. It is defined as below

```
<persistence-unit name="Mongo_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <class>com.jpa.GridListEvent</class>
        <class>com.jpa.HybridListEventBody</class>
        <class>com.jpa.HybridSimpleEventBody</class>
        <class>com.jpa.MongoSimpleEvent</class>
        <class>com.jpa.RefListEvent</class>
        <class>com.jpa.RowElementEntity</class>
        <class>com.jpa.RowReceiptEntity</class>

        <class>com.jpa.OgmSimpleEvent</class>
        <class>com.jpa.OgmSimpleEventBody</class>
      <!--  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>-->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.jtaTMImplementation"
                value="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple" />
            <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.jtaUTImplementation"
                value="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.UserTransactionImple" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"
                value="mongodb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database"
                value="ActingMongo" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host"
                value="127.0.0.1" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port" value="27017" />


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

This is the complete stacktrace

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at it.mypackage.ejb.AbstractDataManager.getEntityManager(AbstractDataManager.java:1145)
    at com.actor.benchmark.Janitor.run(Janitor.java:131)
    at com.actor.benchmark.hybridpersistence.OgmListInsert.main(OgmListInsert.java:42)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:238)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListenerMetadata.getClass(EntityListenerMetadata.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityClassListenerMetadata.process(EntityClassListenerMetadata.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processListeners(EntityAccessor.java:1220)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.addEntityListeners(MetadataProcessor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:591)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Mongo_PU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at it.mypackage.ejb.AbstractDataManager.getFactory(AbstractDataManager.java:100)
    at com.actor.jpa.HybridSimpleEvent.<clinit>(HybridSimpleEvent.java:42)
    ... 15 more
Datasources cleared:522ms [OgmSimpleEvent, OgmSimpleEventBody, JaxListEvent, OgmListEvent, OgmListEventBody, OgmHopListEvent, OgmBigSimpleEvent, OgmBigSimpleEventBody, OgmBigListEvent, OgmBigListEventBody, RotationClass, HybridBigEvent, JaxListEvent, PolyEvent]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
feb 01, 2019 12:36:20 AM it.mypackage.ejb.Bloomy setupMessanger
INFORMAZIONI: Loading messanger it.mypackage.ejb.DefaultMessanger
local bloomy core
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at it.mypackage.ejb.AbstractDataManager.getEntityManager(AbstractDataManager.java:1145)
    at com.actor.benchmark.hybridpersistence.OgmListInsert.main(OgmListInsert.java:70)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.cannotDeployWithoutPredeploy(EntityManagerSetupException.java:190)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at it.mypackage.ejb.AbstractDataManager.getEntityManager(AbstractDataManager.java:1145)
    at com.actor.benchmark.Janitor.run(Janitor.java:131)
    at com.actor.benchmark.hybridpersistence.OgmListInsert.main(OgmListInsert.java:42)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MySQL_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:238)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListenerMetadata.getClass(EntityListenerMetadata.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityClassListenerMetadata.process(EntityClassListenerMetadata.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processListeners(EntityAccessor.java:1220)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.addEntityListeners(MetadataProcessor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:591)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Mongo_PU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at it.mypackage.ejb.AbstractDataManager.getFactory(AbstractDataManager.java:100)
    at com.actor.jpa.HybridSimpleEvent.<clinit>(HybridSimpleEvent.java:42)
    ... 15 more
OgmListEvent [SIZE:10 TABLEA_SIZE:100 TABLEB_SIZE:100] 1ms
```

Comment: Please post the complete exception and how did you run it ?

Comment: Also please check if `Entities` are  registered in the `persistence.xml`

Comment: I added the stacktrace. I run in using `java -jar my.jar`

Comment: I have 2 Persistence Units, maybe this could be a problem in this context?

Comment: Its seems something is not correct with persistence.xml `Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mypackageMongo`

Comment: @Ros5292 I added the PU (the correct name is Mongo_PU)